# Can "magic_quotes_gpc" be enabled in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

In PHP 5.3, can "magic_quotes_gpc" be enabled?

I understand that it is deprecated in PHP 5.3, but a PHP script I am installing requires this otherwise it won't work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be done at the .ini level. It can't be done within a script using ini_set(), because by the time the ini_set() is processed, PHP has already completed startup and the various superglobal arrays (POST/GET/REQUEST/etc...) have been set and will NOT be changed.

You can enable the setting per-script using an Apache `<Files>` directive, since enabling magic quotes for all PHP scripts is a horrible idea:

```
<Files needs_gpc.php>
   php_value magic_quotes_gpc 1
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. What does needs_gpc.php mean?

Comment: That's the name of whatever script you need to have magic quotes enabled for: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files

Answer (score 3):

Then **do not use that script** it is quite bad to have magic quotes enabled.

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

[**DOC**](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)

[**WHY-NOT in DOC**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php)

Comment: If the first thing you have to do is enable magic quotes to get this running, I can only imagine what other nonsense is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate magic_quotes with a short script like:

```
$_GET = array_map("addslashes", $_GET);
$_POST = ...
```

Note that you need a [recursive variant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) actually. And while you're at it you could at least use `_real_escape_string` rather than `addslashes` (which is really only allowable if your database and connection uses ASCII only).

To have that enabled for all scripts use the php.ini option:

```
auto_prepend_file = .../fake_magic_quotes.php
```

At least in PHP 5.3 it's possible to still enable this outdated feature however.

Comment: This won't do if the script in question actually checks if the option is enabled.

Comment: Just guessing from OPs short inquiry; it probably even doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. The feature is disabled by default, but has not been removed. Just modify your php.ini file (or use Marc B's suggestion to enable it for specific script only)